# android:digits attribute no longer works when upgrading to AppCompat 1.4.0

Tags: android, android-appcompat

So, Google recently released a new version of AppCompat, and I gave it a try, but it seems like `android:digits` attribute stopped working.

I want to know if this issue happens only in my project or it is a bug because checking [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#attr_android:digits) shows that this attribute is still working and not deprecated.

Note: I upgraded to SDK 31 as well.

Comment: You are using 1.4.0 or 1.4.0-alpha03 ?

Comment: I'm using the stable 1.4.0.

Comment: Same issue with stable 1.4.0. I have `numberDecimal` editTexts and now users are able to input symbols like space and `-`.

Comment: Got a crash in my custom EditText in 1.4.0. Didn't have it in 1.3.1 :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**
The new version of AppCompat has solved this issue. The new dependency is:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.1'
```